# Conditional Duration Column in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, date-time, conditional, status

We have a SPO list with a metadata column named ***Status*** of type choice that contains the following values:

- Opened
- Closed
- Re-opened

We want to create another column called ***Case Duration*** that will automatically calculate the number of days that have elapsed since the creation of an item in the list. However, this duration must be conditional that is to say trigger according to the value of the status column:

- When the ***Case Status*** field is initially set to open, start the
  ***Case Duration*** field.
- When the ***Case Status*** field change to close, stop ***Case

  Duration*** field and display something like:  Case closed after X
  days been active.
- When the ***Case Status*** field is set to re-open, trigger and
  restart the ***Case Duration*** field.

I wrote this code to format the column with JSON, but this does not take into account the conditionality mentioned above:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=floor((Number(@now)-Number([$Date_x0020_and_x0020_Time_x0020_]))/(1000*60*60*24)) + ' day(s)'" 
}
```

Does anyone have a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on JSON formatting, but my gut tells me that logic may be too complex to implement using it. If custom coding is an option then I would suggest looking at using a SharePoint Framework Field Customizer Extension. That type of logic will be much easier to implement using code. See [Build your first Field Customizer extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-9698) for more information.

Comment: This is what I also thought this logic was too complex to be accomplished by JSON formatting. A Power Automate flow might be able to perform this behavior?

Comment: @Mathieu-Alex Yes, you could also do this using a flow. You would just have to deal with the "item modified loop" issue. In you're not familiar, just search for "power automate item modified loop issue" for a description of the issue and possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you @Rob Windsor! I'm aware of the infinite loop issue. I will try to develop a flow. Given that I'm not an expert in Power Automate, if you have any suggestions, I will be happy to hear them.